# Run docker container in Azure with config in Azure file share (mosquitto broker)

Tags: azure, docker, containers

I would like to run a mosquitto MQTT-broker in Azure as a docker container. (I know azure has an iot-hub... but i would like to have a self-managed broker). I would like to have the mosquitto.conf file in an Azure file share to get a persistent own config and not the default one.
I deployed the docker image as following:

```
az container create \
    --resource-group XXX \
    --name mosquitto \
    --image eclipse-mosquitto \
    --dns-name-label XXX-mqtt \
    --ports 1883 8883\
    --azure-file-volume-account-name XXX \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key XXX \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name XXX \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /fileshare/
```

The docker image ist created and working fine, also the fileshare mount is accessible if i connect into the container.

My question is: How can i define the docker image to use the mosquitto.conf file in the fileshare and not the default one in the docker image?

The mosquitto docker documentation says:

**When running the image, the default configuration values are used. To use a custom configuration file, mount a local configuration file to /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf**

```
$ docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf eclipse-mosquitto
```

How can i pass the `-v mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` argument to the image? With an environment variable?

Thanks for help!

Comment: No, you cannot pass the `-v mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` as the argument for the command `az container create`. It does not support it. What you can do is store the file in the file share and access the file inside the container with mounting the file share to the container.